# PHP foreach loop read files, create array and print file name

Tags: php, foreach, file-get-contents

Could someone help me with this?

I have a folder with some files (without extention)

/module/mail/templates

With these files:

- test
- test2

I want to first loop and read the file names (test and test2) and print them to my html form as dropdown items. This works (the rest of the form html tags are above and under the code below, and omitted here).

But I also want to read each files content and assign the content to a var $content and place it in an array I can use later.

This is how I try to achieve this, without luck:

```
    foreach (glob("module/mail/templates/*") as $templateName)
        {
            $i++;
            $content = file_get_contents($templateName, r); // This is not working
            echo "<p>" . $content . "</p>"; // this is not working
            $tpl = str_replace('module/mail/templates/', '', $templatName);
            $tplarray = array($tpl => $content); // not working
            echo "<option id=\"".$i."\">". $tpl . "</option>";
            print_r($tplarray);//not working
        }
```

Comment: what's going wrong?  Explain what you mean by "not working"

Comment: var_dump( $templateName ); right at the top of your loop. My guess is glob() isn't picking up any files with that pattern.

Comment: The loop runs but does not echo the $content var and print_r does not get printed. So I assume its not picking up or I am doing something wrong. Maybe there is a better way to do this. But I can't see where its going wrong, since it just runs without errors, but does not do what I am trying to.

Comment: var_dump( $templateName ); did not return anything.
But my $tpl var is getting the filenames fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
<?php
$tplarray = array();
$i = 0;
echo '<select>';
foreach(glob('module/mail/templates/*') as $templateName) {
    $content = file_get_contents($templateName); 
    if ($content !== false) {
        $tpl = str_replace('module/mail/templates/', '', $templateName);
        $tplarray[$tpl] = $content; 
        echo "<option id=\"$i\">$tpl</option>" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        trigger_error("Cannot read $templateName");
    } 
    $i++;
}
echo '</select>';
print_r($tplarray);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the array outside of the loop. Then assign it values inside the loop. Don't try to print the array until you are outside of the loop.

The `r` in the call to `file_get_contents` is wrong. Take it out. The second argument to `file_get_contents` is optional and should be a boolean if it is used.

Check that `file_get_contents()` doesn't return `FALSE` which is what it returns if there is an error trying to read the file.

You have a typo where you are referring to `$templatName` rather than `$templateName`.

```
$tplarray = array();
foreach (glob("module/mail/templates/*") as $templateName) {
        $i++;
        $content = file_get_contents($templateName); 
        if ($content !== FALSE) {
            echo "<p>" . $content . "</p>";
        } else {
            trigger_error("file_get_contents() failed for file $templateName");
        } 
        $tpl = str_replace('module/mail/templates/', '', $templateName);
        $tplarray[$tpl] = $content; 
        echo "<option id=\"".$i."\">". $tpl . "</option>";
}
print_r($tplarray);
```

Comment: The `r` in `file_get_contents` would be from [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

Comment: Yea sorry, I started using fopen, and forgot to change it.
Thanks a lot for your help. Now I get the filenames again, but still no output from print_r and echo $content

Comment: Also, it would be more readable to have `echo '<option id="'.$i.'">". $tpl . '</option>';` or `echo "<option id=\"$i\">$tpl</option>";`.

Comment: @Wiseguy Yes, I realized my error and corrected the code above to reflect the intended result. It now says `$tplarray[$tpl] = $content;` Thanks!

Comment: Set your error logging high and check your error log. `trigger_error()` is probably firing, indicating that the `file_get_contents()` is failing. If you have no idea where your logs are and just want to get this done, change `trigger_error()` to `echo()`. Later, go figure out where your logs are and how to set your PHP logging settings because that will help you a lot when trying to debug stuff.

Comment: Thanks I will look look into it, did not know about trigger_error. But changing it to echo still gives no output. :/